# Java POP3 Server and Thunderbird

Tags: java, sockets, exception, server

Why is this exception thrown and how do I get rid of it?
I'm trying to implement a Java POP3 server that communicates with Mozilla Thunderbird.
I've set localhost as server in Thunderbird and it actually connects with my server.
But I can not see what commands Thunderbird is sending because I get an exception, which is thrown when I try to read the client's message. It does not throw this exception when I don't read the client's message.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ServerPOP{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    int POP3Port = 1234;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(POP3Port);
    Socket client;

    while((client = serverSocket.accept()) != null){
    //this is where the thread implementation will come at a later time
    System.out.println("Connection established!");
    InputStream is = client.getInputStream ();
    OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream ();
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader sockin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is));
    PrintWriter sockout = new PrintWriter (os, true);

    // tell client that he is fine
    sockout.println("+OK\r");

    // listen to client's response -- THROWS EXCEPTION!!!
    System.out.println(sockin.readLine());
    }
  }
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at ServerPOP.main(ServerPOP.java:25)
```

The port is 1234 because I am working on a UNIX system and I don't want to sudo around unnecessarily.

Comment: It might by that thunderbird considers your initial greeting invalid, because you send only `+OK\n` and not `+OK\r\n` as required.

Comment: I have corrected that and the exception is almost the same. Only the last line now says ServerPOP.java:25 instead of SeverPOP.java:30